# Error while migrating from .net core 1.1 to .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm upgrading from .net 1.1 to .net 3.1 and have a problem.
In .net core 3.1, i can use appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => this.ApplicationContainer.Dispose())

See below(.net core 1.1)

```
public class Startup
{
  public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    this.Configuration = builder.Build();
  }

  public IContainer ApplicationContainer { get; private set; }

  public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }

  public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddMvc();
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<MyType>().As<IMyType>();
    builder.Populate(services);
    this.ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);
  }

  public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
    IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
  {
      loggerFactory.AddConsole(this.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
      loggerFactory.AddDebug();

      app.UseMvc();

      appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => this.ApplicationContainer.Dispose());
  }
}
```

In .net core 3.1, how do I use
`appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => this.ApplicationContainer.Dispose());`

In my Startup class (.net core 3.1)

```
public class Startup
{
  public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
  {
    this.Configuration = configuration;
  }

  public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

  public ILifetimeScope AutofacContainer { get; private set; }

  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddOptions();
  }

  public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    builder.RegisterModule(new MyApplicationModule());
  }

  public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
    IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
  {
    this.AutofacContainer = app.ApplicationServices.GetAutofacRoot();

    loggerFactory.AddConsole(this.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    app.UseMvc();
  }
}
```

I have reference [here](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting)

Could anyone please help me on these?

Comment: You may not need to explicitly dispose the container. I assume you want to dispose the container to dispose the services it contains. Have you tried it without explicitly disposing the container to see if your services get disposed?

Comment: You know that .NET Core 3.1 is [out of support now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-and-net-core)? Why not make the step to .NET 7?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Maybe I should use it without explicitly disposing of the container.

Answer (score 0):

You should use IHostApplicationLifetime instead of IApplicationLifetime.

IApplicationLifetime is deprecated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime?view=aspnetcore-7.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I use " this.ApplicationContainer.Dispose()" in .net core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IHostApplicationLifetime` instead of `IApplicationLifetime` like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                      IHostApplicationLifetime  hostApplicationLifetime)
{
    hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() =>
    {
        this.ApplicationContainer.Dispose();
    });
}
```